# PHP DOMDocument createElement : square brackets

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, square-bracket

I'm setting up an xml file with DOMDocument like this :

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$document->xmlStandalone = true;
$provider = $document->createElement( "provider" );
$j = $document->createElement( $PARAM );
$j->setAttribute( 'value', "$VALUE" );
$provider->appendChild( $j );
```

This works very well untill... I hit a $PARAM with square brackets in it, like :

```
dirProvider[0].NumberAttributes
```

I have tried using `preg_quote()`, but does not work.
I have tried using `htmlspecialchars()`, but does not work.
I have tried using `createTextNode()` :

```
$j = $document->createTextNode( $PARAM );
$j->setAttribute( 'value', "$VALUE" );
$provider->appendChild( $j );
```

but does not work.

An idea on how I can get these 'special' element names right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Final solution for using regex to remove html nested tags of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823200/final-solution-for-using-regex-to-remove-html-nested-tags-of-the-same-type)

Comment: Where is $pARAM coming from?  In XML, you are more likely to create a `dirProvider` element with another element `NumberAttributes` inside in this sort of structure.